# How to mock a function/method in Vue 3 with Vue Test Utils 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am in the process of converting my project from Vue 2 to 3 and also testing library to Vue test utils 2. Before, mocking methods works like magic:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    greet(text) {
      sayHello('hello world')
    },
    sayHello(text) {
      console.log(text)
    }
  }
}
```

```js
test('should sample', async () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'sayHello')
  wrapper.vm.greet('hello world')
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello world')
})
```

I tried converting it to composition api:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    function greet(text) {
      sayHello(text)
    }

    function sayHello(text) {
      console.log(text)
    }

    return {
      greet,
      sayHello
    }
  }
})
```

and now testing is not working at all

```bash
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: "hello world"

Number of calls: 0
```

How do I mock functions that call another functions in Vue 3 + Vue test utils 2?

Answer (score 0):

you should create your spy functions before the wrapper instance is created (where you use `mount` or `shallowMount`). Creating spies before creating instance and using

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
})
```

in order to reset mocks for following cases should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1951#issuecomment-1019091217

lmiller1990 says that we don't possibly modify values ​​inside of the setup.